# Updating a part of the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have a recycle view that contains 
a description of a comment and a vote count when i press up i need the count to increase this is how it looks like at the moment
[image]

but the problem is when i press up the vote does increase but until i close that fragment and reopen it it does not update

what actually happens is when i press up vote it makes an API call which does some logic and sends it over to android which has a number of the vote for that particular item which was being clicked or upvoted

how can i update that particular record so that i can see the change without reopening the view

code:
CommentItem.java

```
public CommentItem(String id, String description, String voteCount)
{ 
        this.id = id;
        this.description= description;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
}
//getters and setters
```

CommentItemAdapter.java

```
...
private OnItemClickListener mlistener;
/*Interfaces*/
public  interface  OnItemClickListener{
    void VoteUpClick(int position);
    void VoteDownClick(int position);
...
}
...
```

CommentFragment.java

```
 @Override
public void VoteUpClick(final int position) { 
  final CommentItem clickeedItem = 
 mitemList.get(position);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                        AppConfig.URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                 @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
              try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                                 String errorMsg = jObj.getString("msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMsg, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                              
                    } else {
                            String msg= jObj.getString("msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                 }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        }) {
               @Override
             protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
             Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                 params.put("voteType", "up");
                 params.put("commentID", clickeedItem.getId().toString());
                                        return params;
                                    }
                                };
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: You have to update the adapter and then call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: have you tried this? "adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(5,
                                    5);" it will change only reflected items in range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people here had a nice advice to use `DiffUtils`. Thats quite a reasonable way to handle diffs inside dataset of `RecycleView`.

The best way to perform it right now is to use `ListAdapter`, which requires a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` or `AsyncDifferConfig`. A really big pros of ListAdapter is that all differ logic is done on background, which in turns optimizes your UI.
Everything you need is to override this funs: `areItemsTheSame()` and `areContentsTheSame()`, additionally u have `getChangePayload()` - for detailed info about the changed item.
Don't use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` and other range update functions, all of that stuff is handled under-the-hood.

Yours case could be handled via different approaches. I prefer having an intermediate state which will notify user that something happens. So you can locally mark that comment with pending vote up, for example yellow arrow and when response is obtained from back-end you just need to refresh the `data-list` and the `ItemCallback` will do the diff trick for you. When response is retrieved and vote is applied it can be marked as green arrow. Those are just thoughts about the right flow.

In any case everything you need is to use the `ListAdapter.sumbitList(newDataSet)` and the internal `differ` of `ListAdapter` will use ItemCallback to compare old and new list.

Comment: thank you for your advice i shall try this and get back 
on how i fixed it if i am able to :)
need to look for tutorials on this method since i am very new at android programming 
thank u

Comment: so i was able to do it sucessfully i followed a youtube tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAOcL1W05Eg&t=897s

Answer (score 3):

If I get it right, simply `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will update your list. But There is a better way, using `DiffUtils` in recyclerView. That is, comparing old and new list, and updating only the changed item, not changing the whole data set.

Have a look at it out

https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Other approach, is to have the viewHolder reference from the Activity/Or Fragment, when onItemClick happens, by `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)`. Then change view by this view